# Connecting to Windows 8 Cygwin SSH through DD-WRT from WAN?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty, port-forwarding, dd-wrt

I'd like to connect from my work to my home PC/Laptop through Cygwin's SSHD. I have DD-WRT installed on my router and i'm not really sure on how to configure it to allow me to get in.

It works nicely from LAN but not WAN. Putty just hungs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure DD-WRT on your home router to port forward incoming connections from the Internet side, to port 22 on your home PC.

If you want to SSH to multiple devices behind your router, you'll need to pick different ports to forward (e.g. port 34000 to port 22 on your PC, port 34001 to port 22 on your laptop, etc.)

You should be aware that as soon as you open a port in this way, it'll start getting scanned and bots will try logging in through it, so make sure you have strong passwords or use SSH key based authentication.

You should, if possible, on the DD-WRT config lock the port forwarding down to a single source IP address (i.e. your work's public IP address).